# Using Java Time API to add temporal scalar to now and convert to Date

Tags: java, java-11, java-time

Java 11 here. I'm trying to take `LocalDateTime.now()` and add a certain number of mins (`minToAdd`) to it, and convert the result to a new `Date` that is my `LocalDateTime.now()` **plus** `minsToAdd`. I do not want to use Joda or any other library as I'm sure Java is perfectly capable of doing this for me. I would like to avoid using `Calendar` if at all possible, in lieu of `LocalDateTime` since that seems to be the new + recommended API.

My best attempt:

```
LocalDateTime nowLdt = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime expiryLdt = nowLdt.plusMinutes(minsToAdd);
Date expiry = Date.from(expiryLdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

This doesn't throw any errors but returns a `Date` that contains the current day's start of day (00:00:00) time component. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry? I just want  `Date` that represents now + `minsToAdd`.

Comment: Which `Date` class are you trying to use?

Comment: If you are avoiding the legacy class `Calendar`, why use either of the legacy `Date` classes?

Comment: I have to store a value as a `java.util.Date` but would prefer to use newer API calculations if at all possible.

Comment: What? You are calling `atStartOfDay(…)` literally and are wondering that the result “*contains the current day's start of day (00:00:00) time component*”?

Comment: A `java.util.Date` object represents a moment, a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC.  This is equivalent to its replacement, `java.time.Instant`. So your Question makes no sense.

Comment: Some times people think it be like it is, but it do. It do.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. It cannot represent a point in time, but to create an old-fashioned `Date` you do need a point in time. Use `Instant` instead. The other place you are going wrong is by calling `atStartOfDay()`. Read that method name again. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Your Question is confused. But I am guessing that you want to know the calendar date of a moment several minutes from now, as seen through the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
LocalDate ld =
    Instant
    .now()
    .plus( Duration.ofMinutes( someNumber ) )
    .atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() )  // For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. 
    .toLocalDate()
;
```

In contradiction, you also asked for:

> I just want  Date that represents now + minsToAdd.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = 
    java.util.Date
    .from(
        Instant
        .now()
        .plus( Duration.ofMinutes( someNumber ) )
    )
;
```

## Details

I cannot imagine a situation where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do.

The `LocalDateTime` class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset from UTC. So this class cannot represent a point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` instance is inherently ambiguous.

To capture the current moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

If you want a moment a few minutes in the future, call `plus`.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes( someNumber ) ;
Instant later = now.plus( d ) ;
```

Best to avoid `java.util.Date`. But if you must have an instance to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert. Look to new conversion methods added to the legacy classes.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( later ) ;
```

If your goal is to see the calendar date containing that later moment, specify a time zone (`ZoneId`) to determine a `LocalDate` object.

```
ZoneId z = … ;  // If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone: ZoneId.systemDefault()
ZonedDateTime zdt = later.atZone( z ) ;
LocalDate ld = later.toLocalDate() ;
```

---

Avoid both `Date` classes. Along with `Calendar`, they are part of the terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

Comment: I don’t understand the motivation for your edit. Adding five minutes to an instant, followed by converting the result to a `LocalDate` without a time is precisely what the OP doesn’t want. The first version of your answer was better than all others.

Comment: @Holger As I wrote this Answer, every re-reading of the Question got me more confused as to what the OP was trying to achieve. I regret answering now. We should have closed this Question for being confusing and unfocused.

Answer (score 1):

> This doesn't throw any errors but returns a Date that contains the
> current day's start of day (00:00:00) time component. Can anyone spot
> where I'm going awry? I just want  Date that represents now +
> minsToAdd.

You're loosing the time component when calling `toLocalDate()` and re-setting the time to startOfDay with `atStartOfDay()`:

```
Date expiry = Date.from(expiryLdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Try (untested):

```
Date expiry = Date.from(expiryLdt.toInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

Comment: Thanks @Puce (+1), its not liking `ZoneId.systemDefault()` being passed in to `toInstant(...)` as it is not a `ZoneOffset`.